# Use a .jar on client Side as Webapp

Tags: java, browser, web-applications

Is there a technology to load a .jar on a webserver and run it on a client?

Hearing a lot about how usefull webapps are, since you only have to deploy one server and clients mostly only need the allready installed browser, but thinking about how much i don't like javascript and how buggy webapps might be displayed in different browsers, i thought about a webapp beeing loaded into a JRE and executed on the client.

By running the JRE in the browsers context it might be possible to encapsulate it from the OS and allows us to deploy Java-Apps without a seperate download, execute of a client and later removement, since this could be handeled inside the browsers process, just like Java-Script-Apps.

**Edit:** actually other programming-languages/runtime-environments might be fine aswell, just JRE came into my mind as a platform-independent runtime environment

Comment: What you are describing are more or less Java Applets, which have been deemed in many cases to be terribly insecure. As such, browsers have been dropping support for the Java plugin left and right. I believe by next year, all major browsers will no longer support it.

Comment: So is this approach unsafe by its nature or is this a matter of implementation? Might the answer just be: make a new Javascript which is more like java, to make it work they way i want?

Comment: Well first off, it is a relatively ancient technology. If a website were still using applets, I personally would probably laugh, and never visit that website again. Secondly, its not just unsafe by nature, it will literally be impossible by next year, as no browsers will support it. My advice to you would be to recognize the massive strides in browser technology that have been made (including cross-browser compatibility) and plan to develop a traditional web application.